# Bundle CSS in publishable NX React library

Tags: reactjs, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx.dev

I created a publishable React library that contains some custom styles. When I use this library (component) within a demo application in the NX project, I do not need to include any CSS styles - they just work.

Now I published this library into my private NPM registry and I want to use this package in a separate application - suddenly my CSS files are not automatically included and I need to include JS files as well as CSS files.

Is there a way to bundle CSS files automatically into a build? So that in my consuming app, all I have to do is to `import {MyComponent} from 'my-component';` and there will be CSS files included as well?

thanks

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: unfortunately not :( I have to manually include my component as well as its CSS file... it's pretty annoying

Comment: I figured it out.  https://nx.dev/packages/rollup/executors/rollup#extractcss